How to change the default icon on Electron Desktop App 2024
Ive' been following the docs on how to change the default icon on my eletron app, but nothing seems working i am using npm run make
this is my forge.config.js file, what i want is to change the default icon in the window and the icon in the desktop shortcut and system tray. on development it works but once compiled as .exe my custom icon does not appear
const { FusesPlugin } = require("@electron-forge/plugin-fuses");
const { FuseV1Options, FuseVersion } = require("@electron/fuses");

module.exports = {
  packagerConfig: {
    asar: true,
  },
  icon: "images/favicon.ico",
  rebuildConfig: {},
  makers: [
    {
      name: "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
      config: {
        certificateFile: "./cert.pfx",
        certificatePassword: process.env.CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD,
        authors: "Dev",
        description: "My App",
        setupIcon: "images/favicon.ico",
        icon: "images/favicon.ico",
      },
      platforms: ["win32"],
    },
    {
      name: "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
      platforms: ["darwin"],
    },
    {
      name: "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
      config: {},
    },
    {
      name: "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
      config: {},
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    {
      name: "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives",
      config: {},
    },
    // Fuses are used to enable/disable various Electron functionality
    // at package time, before code signing the application
    new FusesPlugin({
      version: FuseVersion.V1,
      [FuseV1Options.RunAsNode]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableCookieEncryption]: true,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableNodeOptionsEnvironmentVariable]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableNodeCliInspectArguments]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableEmbeddedAsarIntegrityValidation]: true,
      [FuseV1Options.OnlyLoadAppFromAsar]: true,
    }),
  ],
};

Here is my main.js
const { app, BrowserWindow, Tray, nativeImage } = require("electron");

const createWindow = () => {
  const icon = nativeImage.createFromPath("./favicon.ico");
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1600,
    height: 900,
    minWidth: 900,
    minHeight: 600,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    webPreferences: {
      devTools: !app.isPackaged,
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
    icon: icon,
  });

  win.loadURL("https://nbook-app.web.app");
  win.setIcon(icon);
};

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow();
  const icon = nativeImage.createFromPath("./favicon.ico");
  const tray = new Tray(icon);
  tray.setToolTip("Nbook");
});

if (require("electron-squirrel-startup")) app.quit();



Your icon image location is images/favicon.ico or in the same dir as the main ?
otherwise, sometimes you need to delete the app Data/cache when it's not deleted after uninstalling electron exe
Another last cause may be the config that is copied from the original one in the release/app directory.
